# React-Router: Update route's component on new props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

***App.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Login from './Login';
import Courses from './Courses';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  setCredentials = ({ username, password }) => {
    this.setState({
      username,
      password
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route
          path='/'
          component={Login}
          setCredentials={this.setCredentials}
          />
        <Route
          path='/courses'
          component={Courses}
          credentials={this.state}
          />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The `Login` component takes in credentials from user, verifies them via an API call, updates `App`'s state with them, and then redirects to the `Courses` component using `this.props.router.push('/courses')`.

The `Courses` component should take in the **updated** credentials (i.e. `App`'s updated state) as props, and afterwards perform an API call to fetch that user's courses.

How can I detect the updates in `App`'s state inside the `Courses` component? Am I doing it wrong altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pass props to route's component correctly:

```
   <Route
      path='/'
      component={(props) => <Login  setCredentials={this.setCredentials} {...props} />}
      />
```

and NOT:

```
   <Route
      path='/'
      component={Login}
      setCredentials={this.setCredentials}
      />
```

The same for the `Courses` component, you pass extra-props the same way:

```
    <Route
      path='/courses'
      component={(props) => <Courses credentials={this.state} {...props} />}
      />
```

And NOT:

```
    <Route
      path='/courses'
      component={Courses}
      credentials={this.state}
      />
```

Which answers the question:

> How can I detect the updates in App's state inside the Courses component?

since `crendentials` becomes a prop of `Courses` and its value `state` of `App`.

Answer (score 0):

As you said with the courses component reading from props you could have a lifecycle hook like so in the courses component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.isAuthenticated && this.props.credentials !== nextProps.credentials) {
    // perform fetch for courses here
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `componentWillReceiveProps` never gets invoked.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMaged The new answer will resolve the issue of `componentWillReceiveProps` never gets invoked as before you were setting the properties to the react-router component and not your own.